# removeAt removes elements in passed ArrayList too

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist

I've never saw this

```
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        private fun eraseOldLocations() {
        val a: ArrayList<Ub> =myUbs
        val minTime: Long = (now- tenDaysago)
        val z = misUbs.size
        for(i in 0 until z){
            if( myUbs[i].time <minTime) {
                a.removeAt(i)
            }
        }
        myUbs = a
    }
```

each time the condition is fulfilled, the element in the position i of a is removed ... BUT also from the myUbs !!! myUbs is a public object, so as the loop continues, appears an error because the variable i exceeds the size of myUbs ...
The function eraseOldLocations() must delete elements with date older than ten days ago. Why is this happening?

Comment: `a` and `myUbs` both *refer* to the same ArrayList. There is only one list. The `=` assignment operator doesn't copy the list, just the reference to the list.

Comment: this happens with all public objects ? sorry my ignorance

Comment: Doesn`t matter if it's public. Whenever you assign an object to a variable, the object is neither cloned nor modified. You simply have another variable pointing to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a shallow copy of `myUbs`, so that references of list will differ and changes won't reflect to each other:

```kotlin
val a: MutableList<Ub> = myUbs.toMutableList()
```

MutableList is essentially the same, but if you want ArrayList explicitly (althrough not recommended in Kotlin) you can call ArrayList constructor to delegate to the Collection specified. That essentially does the shallow copy as well:

```kotlin
val a: ArrayList<Ub> = ArrayList(myUbs)
```